# Unable to Join table to other tables inside a stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I've been granted select access to a table and I am able to run queries and join to other tables as well and get results back. But when I put the same statement inside a stored procedure, I get no results back.

Answer (score 0):

No results or error?
Grants to work in SP must be given to the user not to the role

Comment: Thank you, will check with the DBA but I have other stored procs that have joins and they work fine, it's just that one specific table that seems to be the problem.

Comment: If you solve the problem post here the solution. Thanks